# [measurements], [field-measurements], [in-situ-measurements] tags; do we need all three? Some definitions for the last two?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tagging

I just asked [How did they know that there was a "desert tsunami" in a Death Valley cave after a 7.6 magnitude earthquake near the southwest of Mexico?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/24357/6031) and found there are three "measurement" tags and was unable to figure out which, or how many to add to it.

**Question:** Do we need all three of these tags? Perhaps some definitions for the last two?

- [measurements](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/measurements) **134** questions

> Questions related to acquiring, processing and interpreting field measurements of any kind. Including instrumentation and data analysis.

- [field-measurements](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-measurements) **25** questions

> The field-measurements tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

- [in-situ-measurements](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/in-situ-measurements) **5** questions

> The in-situ-measurements tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

Answer (score 2):

The second tag, [field-measurements](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-measurements), seems redundant, as "field measurements" is already included in the description of the [measurements](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/measurements) tag... So it could probably become a synonym.

*In-situ* is more tricky... In geophysics it is used for field measurements (as opposed to remote sensing), while other disciplines use the term for measurements that are definitely not done in the field, but rather in a lab (e.g., experimental petrologists use it for synchrotron measurements, while geochemists use it for mass spectrometer measurements). I'm not sure what we should do with this one, although it does not seem to be widely used...

Comment: To simplify things I would suggest the retention of the [measurements] tag & the abandonment of the other two, but the guidance for the [measurements] tag be expanded to include the other two. Elements of this answer could be used to expand that guidance.